# How to read preference with glance Widget Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to do a weather app with a widget.
I call open weather map api and I can see the wether in the main screen on the phone.
I save them in dataStore with :

```
mainViewModel.setCity(city)
```

```
fun setCity(city: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        preferenceManager.setWeatherCity(city)
    }
}
```

```
suspend fun setWeatherCity(city: String){
    application.applicationContext.pref.edit { preference ->
        preference[stringPreferencesKey("weather_city")] = city
    }
}
```

I read them in the widget with :

```
val prefs = currentState<Preferences>()
val city: String = remember {
    prefs[stringPreferencesKey("weather_city")] ?: "Paris"
}
```

But for exemple if I save **Cancun** on the widget there is always the default value **Paris**

Someone know why or what can I do to solve it ?

Comment: Widgets have their own preferences, you can access them using [updateAppWidgetState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/state/package-summary#updateappwidgetstate_1)

Comment: Yes I saw it but still not working

Comment: Do you mean prefs doesn't updating? Or you can't read it in widget? What if right after updating the preferences you try to read and log them to see if the value changes?

Comment: Could you check this answer? It will help you probably. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168589/10672178

Comment: I can read from the widget but after the worker, Not directly when I save in preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very good exemple If it can help someone :
https://itnext.io/schedule-image-displaying-in-glance-widget-with-work-manager-api-cc474ed8571c

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.